# Is there a way to color code matching parentheses in R studio?

Tags: rstudio, parentheses

Everything I am finding online discusses highlighting matching parentheses, but I'm wondering if there is a specific editor theme or perhaps something else I could use for R studio that will **color code** matching parentheses within nested parentheses. New R user here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @manetsus I've been using google searches such as "how to color code parenthesis using theme editor for r studio" to no avail. https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/the-11-best-code-editors-available-in-2015 I am looking for something free and was looking at Atom https://atom.io/packages/r-exec. Hacking a theme editor is beyond my purview which is why I was searching for an editor theme that does this already.

Comment: did my answer help you? @ENIAC

Comment: I understand that this is a feature available in v1.4. currently available in beta/dailies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to do this in RStudio however it only last the length of a click.

Given this simple code:

```
for (x in 1:10){
  print("Line 1")
  print("line 2")
}
```

If you double click right after any sign that requires a closing sing such as

```
()
{}
```

Then the code on the parenthesis will be highlighted. 
Example see what's inside the first parenthesis
[image: Code example 1]

Or see the content of the for loop

[image: Code example 2]